# Android: Storing data internally

Tags: java, android, storage

I am making a game for android. The game will have a scoreboard - but i haven't gotten to that part yet. At the moment I am trying to implement Player profiles - Players should be able to create a profile with their name - and their profile should be saved permanently. It is essential I get this part working before creating the scoreboard - that will use the player profiles to save scores.

What is the best way of saving this data permanently (local)? and being able to edit it dynamically?

keep in mind, I may want to keep several fields of data for each profile so I dont think a .txt file would be best perhaps a small database, or XML file? how would I implement these with android?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a database,, like SQLite or Realm. If you want to have your content providder and loaders, then SQLite is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can save your data in SQLite Database (Like [Francesc said)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2741273/francesc). It's very easy to implement and you can find examples here: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

```
Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
```

[Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

```
Store private data on the device memory.
```

[External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

```
Store public data on the shared external storage.
```

[SQLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

```
Store structured data in a private database.
```

[Network Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw)

```
Store data on the web with your own network server.
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The best & easiest way to save `String`, `Integers` etc. is using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

It's as easy as

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE, "data");
String name = prefs.getString("name"); // Load name
prefs.edit().putString(newName).commit(); // Save name
```